# Ссылка на метод экземпляра

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

Не могу понять как это работает

```
public interface MyFunc<T> {
    boolean func(T v1, T v2);
}

public class HighTemp {
    private int hTemp;

    HighTemp(int ht) {
        hTemp = ht;
    }

    boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2) {
        return hTemp == ht2.hTemp;
    }

    boolean lessThanTemp(HighTemp ht2) {
        return hTemp < ht2.hTemp;
    }
}

public class InctanceMethWithObjectRefDemo {

static <T> int counter(T[] vals, MyFunc<T> f, T v) {
    int count = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < vals.length; i++)
        if(f.func(vals[i], v)) count++;

    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count;

    HighTemp[] weekDayHighs = { new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(82),
                                new HighTemp(90), new HighTemp(89),
                                new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(91),
                                new HighTemp(84), new HighTemp(83)};

    count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::sameTemp, new HighTemp(89));
    System.out.println("Дней, когда максимальная температура была 89: " + count);

    HighTemp[] weekDayHighs2 = { new HighTemp(32), new HighTemp(12),
                                 new HighTemp(24), new HighTemp(19),
                                 new HighTemp(18), new HighTemp(12),
                                 new HighTemp(-1), new HighTemp(13)};

    count = counter(weekDayHighs2, HighTemp::sameTemp, new HighTemp(12));
    System.out.println("Дней, когда температура была 12: " + count);

    count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::lessThanTemp, new HighTemp(89));
    System.out.println("Дней, когда температура была меньше 89: " + count);

    count = counter(weekDayHighs2, HighTemp::lessThanTemp, new HighTemp(19));
    System.out.println("Дней, когда температура была меньше 19: " + count);
    }
}
```

а именно это f.func(vals[i], v). Почему в f.func(vals[i], v) передается 2 аргумента, когда в переменную f передается ссылка на метод sameTemp, который принимает 1 аргумент. Почему и как это работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нестатические методы неявно принимают аргумент `this`, указывающий на экземпляр объекта, метод которого вызывается.

Comment: Но sameTemp не является статичным

Comment: Можно поподробнее я не понял. Для чего они this принимают?

Comment: Чтобы объект мог управлять своим состоянием. Но если это для вас не очевидно, то пока просто примите как данность, что виртуальная машина так устроена.

Answer (score 1):

Тема: "Передача ссылки на метод произвольного объекта определённого типа".

теперь к вашему коду:

Вот инструкция с вызовом метода, который принимает так называемую "ссылку на метод произвольного объекта определённого типа" - *HighTemp::sameTemp*

```
count = counter(weekDayHighs2, HighTemp::sameTemp, new HighTemp(12));
```

Попробуем представить работу Java, при встрече *HighTemp::sameTemp* так:

1. Ищет метод *sameTemp* в классе *HighTemp*.
2. Определяет что он не "static" (если был бы "static", то тут совсем другое поведение);
3. В найденый метод `boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2)` **неявно**, в начало, добавляет параметр `HighTemp x`. В результате сигнатура уже выглядит примерно так: `boolean sameTemp(HighTemp x, HighTemp ht2)`
4. Теперь, полученную и слегка "подправленную" (уже с ДВУМЯ параметрами) сигнатуру
   метода *sameTemp* `boolean sameTemp(HighTemp x, HighTemp ht2)` сравнивает с сигнатурой метода функционального интерфейса *MyFunc* `boolean func(T v1, T v2)`, у которой тоже ДВА параметра одинакового типа, и такое же возвращаемое значение.
   С этим всё, надеюсь понятно.

далее, когда Java встречает это варажение (в методе *counter*):

```
f.func(vals[i], v)
```

перед тем как его исполнить, происходит <strike>мэджик</strike> следующее:

метод интерфейса `boolean func(T v1, T v2)` (с двумя параметрами) трансформируется в наш изначальный метод *sameTemp* `boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2)` (с одним параметром) а именно:

5. аргумент `vals[i]` - выносится из скобок и подставляется вместо `f`, становясь тем самым "произвольным объектом определённого типа" (из темы). То есть в пункте 3 этот параметр неявно был добавлен, а теперь он "исчезает" (объект `vals[i]` "вытянули" и он (параметр) больше не нужен!).
6. `func(v)` c оставшимся одним параметром, становится `sameTemp(v)`

в итоге получаем, что Java исполняя это:

```
f.func(vals[i], v)
```

фактически исполняет это:

```
vals[i].sameTemp(v)
```

Важно понять, что метод `sameTemp(HighTemp ht2)` может иметь хоть 5 параметров!
В любом случае (по приведённой схеме в п.п.3 и далее) в начало списка параметров будет неявно добавлен шестой параметр (в нашем случае - типа *HighTemp*), чтобы в дальнейшем получить в этом параметре "произвольный" объект, извлечь его, и использовать как тот самый "произвольный объект" метод которого Java и будет вызывать.
(если у метода *sameTemp* было бы 5 параметров, то тогда у метода функционального интерфейса должно быть их 6. Первый из которых должен быть обязательно "определённого типа" (под "определённым типом" подразумевается класс, с методом "произвольного экземпляра" которого мы хотим ассоциировать метод интерфейса))

Примерно поняв, как это работает, название самой темы: - "Передача ссылки на метод произвольного объекта определённого типа" должна звучать слегка дружелюбнее).

P.S. Пример рассматриваемого кода из книги Г.Шилдта, как по мне - не самый удачный. Слишком много лишнего, что начинающего только отвлекает от сути изучаемого вопроса.